# Where to put a method?

Tags: php, oop

I've one question.

I'm currently having two classes:
A class called RoomFactory, which builds Room Objects and a class called User.
A User can own Rooms.

Now I wanted to get the Rooms of a User. But where do I put the method?

I could put the method in RoomFactory and call it **GetRoomsOfUser($UserObject)**, I could put the method in the User Object and call it **GetRooms()** or I could put it in both.

What would be the best practice for this?

Comment: put it to user and next call it like getUserRooms($UserObject)

Comment: The comment above isn't English.

Comment: Simple to Englishe(tm) translation for @Coulton:  "I say, old boy! You should put it into the `user` class and subsequently call it as in this example:  `getUserRooms($UserObject)`. "

Comment: Thank God for that, it's useful to anyone who views this post now! :D

Comment: But why should I reference an User Object, while I'm in the User Class?

Comment: If you were dealing with a User **instance**, then it would make no sense to pass in the User: `$user->getUserRooms($user)` but if you had a User **class** where you kept User logic, then it may make sense: `User::getUserRooms($user)`. The second isn't really OO though, just procedural code wrapped in a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should live on the User object. The job of the RoomFactory is to build Room objects, not to fetch User-related objects.

Comment: Do you mean UserFactory or RoomFactory?

Comment: I meant RoomFactory. Corrected, thanks.